# How to display only the input fields of that option in vue js html when using v-for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I tried several solutions.

My issue is that when i select option 1, i am getting the input fields related to that only. Since i am using v-for, i have an add button, so i can select another option now but when i select that option, both the input fields change relative to the second option. How can I able to show input fields corresponding to the options selected.

The code I tried is

My json data is

```
[{
    "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fab",
    "refId": 7929,
    "type": "text",
    "text": "Indian Act 1931",
    "__v": 0,
    "feilds": [{
        "refId": 7912,
        "name": "arms(if any)",
        "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fac",
        "sections": [],
        "subFeilds": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb6",
    "refId": 7930,
    "type": "text",
    "text": "Narcotic",
    "__v": 0,
    "feilds": [{
        "refId": 7913,
        "name": "qty",
        "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb7",
        "sections": [],
        "subFeilds": []
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbbf",
    "refId": 7933,
    "type": "option",
    "text": "Ker",
    "__v": 0,
    "feilds": [{
        "refId": 7918,
        "name": "wild",
        "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc2",
        "sections": ["sec1", "sec2"],
        "subFeilds": [{
            "refId": 17890,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc4"
        }, {
            "refId": 7891,
            "name": "item",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc3"
        }]
    }, {
        "refId": 7919,
        "name": "enc",
        "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc0",
        "sections": ["sec2"],
        "subFeilds": [{
            "refId": 7892,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc1"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

I am showing my fields based on the json data

My js fiddle is

https://jsfiddle.net/u22t359x/1/

Here you can view what is happening with me. When I select option 1, input fields are coming, when i click on add new rule and select another option, all input fields are been replaced by input fields of that option.

Please have a check and help me to have a solution.

First when I select Indian Act 1931 from dropdown input field arms(if any) comes. Now click on Add Another Rule. Select Narcotic from the list. Now input field of Indian Act 1931 has changed to qty. This should remain as arms(if any). Input field of Narcotic should be qty

Answer (score 0):

> `<div v-else-if = "ter === 'option'">` => `<div v-else-if = "bok.ter === 'option'">`

```js
  var regBox = new Vue({
    el: "#regBox",
    data: {
      type: '',
      text: '',
      feilds: [
        /*{
                name : null,
                sections:[],
                subfeilds : [{name:null}],      
            }*/
      ],
      data: [{
        "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fab",
        "refId": 7929,
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Indian Act 1931",
        "__v": 0,
        "feilds": [{
          "refId": 7912,
          "name": "arms(if any)",
          "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fac",
          "sections": [],
          "subFeilds": []
        }]
      }, {
        "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb6",
        "refId": 7930,
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Narcotic",
        "__v": 0,
        "feilds": [{
          "refId": 7913,
          "name": "qty",
          "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb7",
          "sections": [],
          "subFeilds": []
        }]
      }, {
        "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbbf",
        "refId": 7933,
        "type": "option",
        "text": "Ker",
        "__v": 0,
        "feilds": [{
          "refId": 7918,
          "name": "wild",
          "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc2",
          "sections": ["sec1", "sec2"],
          "subFeilds": [{
            "refId": 17890,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc4"
          }, {
            "refId": 7891,
            "name": "item",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc3"
          }]
        }, {
          "refId": 7919,
          "name": "enc",
          "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc0",
          "sections": ["sec2"],
          "subFeilds": [{
            "refId": 7892,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc1"
          }]
        }]
      }],
      filesa: '',
      allen: '',
      all: '',
      rule: '',
      plan_amt: '',
      allenn1: '',
      rules: [{
        name: null,
        section: null,
        data: [{
          head: null,
          value: null
        }]
      }],
    },
    mounted: function() {
      setTimeout(_ => {
        this.data = [{
          "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fab",
          "refId": 7929,
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Indian Act 1931",
          "__v": 0,
          "feilds": [{
            "refId": 7912,
            "name": "arms(if any)",
            "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fac",
            "sections": [],
            "subFeilds": []
          }]
        }, {
          "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb6",
          "refId": 7930,
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Narcotic",
          "__v": 0,
          "feilds": [{
            "refId": 7913,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb7",
            "sections": [],
            "subFeilds": []
          }]
        }, {
          "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbbf",
          "refId": 7933,
          "type": "option",
          "text": "Ker",
          "__v": 0,
          "feilds": [{
            "refId": 7918,
            "name": "wild",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc2",
            "sections": ["sec1", "sec2"],
            "subFeilds": [{
              "refId": 17890,
              "name": "qty",
              "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc4"
            }, {
              "refId": 7891,
              "name": "item",
              "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc3"
            }]
          }, {
            "refId": 7919,
            "name": "enc",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc0",
            "sections": ["sec2"],
            "subFeilds": [{
              "refId": 7892,
              "name": "qty",
              "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc1"
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }, 1000)
    },
    methods: {
      addNewRules: function() {
        this.rules.push({
          name: null,
          section: null,
          data: [{
            head: null,
            value: null
          }]
        });
      },
      setCost(bok) {
        var vm = this;
        var name = bok.name;
        var obj = this.data.filter(o=>o.refId==bok.name)[0] || {allen1:[]}
        bok.ter = obj.type;
        bok.allen = obj.text;
        bok.allen1 = obj.feilds;
      },
      setRule(bok) {
        for (let rule of bok.allen1) {
          if (rule.refId === bok.rule) {
            bok.al2 = rule.subFeilds;
          }
        }
      },
      handelSubmit: function(e) {
        var vm = this;
        data = {};
        data['feilds'] = this.feilds;
        data['type'] = this.type;
        data['text'] = this.text;
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:4000/add/act/',
          data: data,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(e) {
            if (e.status) {
              alert("Registration Success");
            } else {
              alert("Registration Failed");
              vm.response = e;
            }
          }
        });
        return false;
      },
    },
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 mr-auto" id="regBox">
  <form class="form" method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit($event);">
    <div class="card-content" v-for="(bok, index) in rules" :key="index">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">
              <i class="material-icons">room</i>
            </span>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control"  v-model="bok.name" name="type" @change="setCost(bok)">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
            <option v-for="post in data" v-bind:value="post.refId" >{{post.text}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="bok.ter === 'text'">
        <div v-for="(all,index) in bok.allen1" :key="index">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                  <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                  {{all.name}}
                </span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div v-else-if = "bok.ter === 'option'">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="bok.rule" name="rule" @change="setRule(bok)">
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
          <option v-for="pl in bok.allen1" v-bind:value="pl.refId" >{{pl.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <div v-for="all3 in bok.al2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                  <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                  {{all3.name}}
                </span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {{bok.al2}}
      </div>
      <div v-else>erg
      </div>
      {{bok.al2}}
      <h3>The JSON value of <code>bok</code></h3>
      <textarea rows="3" cols="75%" readonly class="form-control">{{ JSON.stringify(bok) }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <a @click="addNewRules">Add Another Rule</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

[image: set bok value]

[image]

Comment: Sir, please check the answer given. There is no change in the ouput. First when I select Indian Act 1931 from dropdown input field arms(if any) comes. Now click on Add Another Rule. Select Narcotic from the list. Now input field of Indian Act 1931 has changed to qty. This should remain as arms(if any). Input field of Narcotic should be qty.

Comment: sir @jacky can you plz provide me a solution

Comment: sir can i ask a doubt. From where you are dsiplaying "ter":"text","allen":"Indian Act 1931","allen1":[{"refId":7912,"name":"arms(if any)","_id":"5b052126c3a5552bac060fac","sections":[],"subFeilds":[]}]} in {{bok}}

Comment: I uploaded two screenshots, I don't know if this will explain your problem.

Comment: sir there is one problem remaining. When I select ker, options are not loading. Actually based on that options there will be another input field coming. But it is not working now. just have a check

Comment: hello sir, did you see with the same

Comment: sir thanks a lot.. I need one more help sir,, can we talk in discussion page

Comment: when i select ker, options are loading, how can i able to select multiple options from there

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
var regBox = new Vue({
    el: "#regBox",
    data: {
      type: '',
      text: '',
      feilds: [
        /*{
                name : null,
                sections:[],
                subfeilds : [{name:null}],      
            }*/
      ],
      data: [{
        "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fab",
        "refId": 7929,
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Indian Act 1931",
        "__v": 0,
        "feilds": [{
          "refId": 7912,
          "name": "arms(if any)",
          "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fac",
          "sections": [],
          "subFeilds": []
        }]
      }, {
        "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb6",
        "refId": 7930,
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Narcotic",
        "__v": 0,
        "feilds": [{
          "refId": 7913,
          "name": "qty",
          "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb7",
          "sections": [],
          "subFeilds": []
        }]
      }, {
        "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbbf",
        "refId": 7933,
        "type": "option",
        "text": "Ker",
        "__v": 0,
        "feilds": [{
          "refId": 7918,
          "name": "wild",
          "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc2",
          "sections": ["sec1", "sec2"],
          "subFeilds": [{
            "refId": 17890,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc4"
          }, {
            "refId": 7891,
            "name": "item",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc3"
          }]
        }, {
          "refId": 7919,
          "name": "enc",
          "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc0",
          "sections": ["sec2"],
          "subFeilds": [{
            "refId": 7892,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc1"
          }]
        }]
      }],
      filesa: '',
      allen: '',
      all: '',
      rule: '',
      plan_amt: '',
      allenn1: '',
      rules: [{
        name: null,
        section: null,
        rule:[],
        data: [{
          head: null,
          value: null
        }]
      }],
    },
    mounted: function() {
      setTimeout(_ => {
        this.data = [{
          "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fab",
          "refId": 7929,
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Indian Act 1931",
          "__v": 0,
          "feilds": [{
            "refId": 7912,
            "name": "arms(if any)",
            "_id": "5b052126c3a5552bac060fac",
            "sections": [],
            "subFeilds": []
          }]
        }, {
          "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb6",
          "refId": 7930,
          "type": "text",
          "text": "Narcotic",
          "__v": 0,
          "feilds": [{
            "refId": 7913,
            "name": "qty",
            "_id": "5b05244f90a7000f44bcbbb7",
            "sections": [],
            "subFeilds": []
          }]
        }, {
          "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbbf",
          "refId": 7933,
          "type": "option",
          "text": "Ker",
          "__v": 0,
          "feilds": [{
            "refId": 7918,
            "name": "wild",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc2",
            "sections": ["sec1", "sec2"],
            "subFeilds": [{
              "refId": 17890,
              "name": "qty",
              "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc4"
            }, {
              "refId": 7891,
              "name": "item",
              "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc3"
            }]
          }, {
            "refId": 7919,
            "name": "enc",
            "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc0",
            "sections": ["sec2"],
            "subFeilds": [{
              "refId": 7892,
              "name": "qty",
              "_id": "5b052b4090a7000f44bcbbc1"
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }, 1000)
    },
    methods: {
      addNewRules: function() {
        this.rules.push({
          name: null,
          section: null,
          rule:[],
          data: [{
            head: null,
            value: null
          }]
        });
      },
      setCost(bok) {
        var vm = this;
        var name = bok.name;
        var obj = this.data.filter(o=>o.refId==bok.name)[0] || {allen1:[]}
        bok.ter = obj.type;
        bok.allen = obj.text;
        bok.allen1 = obj.feilds;
      },
      handelSubmit: function(e) {
        var vm = this;
        data = {};
        data['feilds'] = this.feilds;
        data['type'] = this.type;
        data['text'] = this.text;
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:4000/add/act/',
          data: data,
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(e) {
            if (e.status) {
              alert("Registration Success");
            } else {
              alert("Registration Failed");
              vm.response = e;
            }
          }
        });
        return false;
      },
    },
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 mr-auto" id="regBox">
  <form class="form" method="POST" v-on:submit.prevent="handelSubmit($event);">
    <div class="card-content" v-for="(bok, index) in rules" :key="index">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">
              <i class="material-icons">room</i>
            </span>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control"  v-model="bok.name" name="type" @change="setCost(bok)">
            <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
            <option v-for="post in data" v-bind:value="post.refId" >{{post.text}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-if="bok.ter === 'text'">
        <div v-for="(all,index) in bok.allen1" :key="index">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">
                  <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                  {{all.name}}
                </span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="bok.data[0].head" >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div v-else-if = "bok.ter === 'option'">
        <select class="form-control" v-model="bok.rule" name="rule" multiple>
          <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose Type here</option>
          <option v-for="pl in bok.allen1" :value="pl" >{{pl.name}}</option>
        </select> Hold down the control key and click the option to select multiple options
        <div v-for="item in bok.rule">
          <div v-for="all3 in item.subFeilds">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                    {{all3.name}}
                  </span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div v-else>erg
      </div>
      {{bok.al2}}
      <h3>The JSON value of <code>bok</code></h3>
      <textarea rows="3" cols="75%" readonly class="form-control">{{ JSON.stringify(bok) }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <a @click="addNewRules">Add Another Rule</a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: sir, exactly the same. thanks.. but one more problem

Comment: So, when I select 1st option indian act,1931, an input field comes there arms(if any). So in that case i need my v-model as bok.data[0].head.arms(if any). in next case when I select option 2. field with qty comes, so i need to send data as bok.data[0].head.qty

Comment: In the 3rd case 1 select ker, both wild and enc comes as dropdown. On clicking this another input field comes. When I click wild, qty and item comes. So, I need to send this values as bok.data[0].value.qty and bok.data[0].value.item. when i click  enc , qty comes so, i need to send values as bok.data[0].value.qty

Comment: hello sir, could you please help me